# Is there any solution for converting any irregular shape to any constructible regular polygon without changing area through pure construction?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, geometric-construction

Is there any solution for converting any irregular shape to any constructible regular polygon without changing area through pure construction?

Comment: What is the method of construction? Straight edge compass construction? Construction with the latest technology no holds barred? Something in between?

Comment: Yes, compass straight edge construction

Comment: FYI, the [Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace–Bolyai–Gerwien_theorem) states that any two polygons of the same area are "equidecomposable": either polygon can be dissected into pieces that re-assemble to form the other. The standard proof is *constructive*, telling you exactly how you can dissect one polygon to get the usable pieces. (These pieces aren't necessarily *optimal*, however.) The standard steps are uncomplicated, but I don't recall offhand if they're achievable entirely by straightedge-and-compass operations.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a polygon having $n$ sides, we can construct an equivalen polygon having $n-1$ sides.

Draw diagonal $DF$ and parallel line to $DF$ passing through $E$. This parallel intersects $CD$ in $H$. The triangles $FDE$ and $FDH$ are equivalent because they have the same base and the same height. So the polygon $ABCHFG$ is equivalent to $ABCDEFG$ and has one side less.

This construction can ideally be done until we get a triangle equivalent to the starting polygon.

A rectangle  equivalent to the triangle can be easily constructed.

See the second picture below. $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$, $FE\parallel AB$ and lines $AF,DE$ are perpendicular to $AB$.

A square equivalent to the rectangle $ABCD$ can be constructed in the following way (see third picture below).

With center in $B$ draw an arc having radius $BC$ which intersects the line $AB$ in $F$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AF$. With center in $M$ and radius $AM$ draw a semicircle that intersects the line $CB$ in $H$. The $AHF$ is a right triangle and $BF\cdot AB=BH^2$.

So the red square is equivalent to the blue rectangle.

[image]
[image]
[image]